# Aggregation of data in microsecond bars in kdb+

Tags: database, timestamp, time-series, aggregation, kdb

How can I use the xbar function to aggregate rows in a table in 10 microsecond bars. The table consists of the columns `timestamp` and `val`. For aggregating in millisecond bars instead I already know that I can simply use `timestamp.datetime` in the xbar query.

A possible result table should look as follows:

```
timestamp                 | val
--------------------------| ---
2015.12.02D12:19:44.434430| 2
2015.12.02D12:19:44.434440| 8
2015.12.02D12:19:44.434450| 5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work:

```
d:([]t:asc .z.P+100*10?100;v:10?10)
select avg v by (10*1000) xbar t from d
```

Note that the output time column is still a 'timestamp' ("p") type, however the values are barred in microseconds.

I wrote the first xbar argument as (10*1000) for clarity. To change to 5 microseconds you can do (5*1000) etc.

Comment: May be more convenient to use `timespan` on LHS of `xbar` - example: `select avg v by 0D00:00:00.01 xbar t from d` - which will give you 10ms buckets.